# Is there any way to get the matched string or word in mysql

Tags: mysql

I am using Match() Against() in mysql.
What I want to do is somehow get the keyword that is matched with the string.

lets say the keyword is 'rain water'
and I want to find it in the table. Since its match() Against() It will match both rain and water individually and thats find. But I want to get the word which is matched.

Like if rain is matched i need the word rain if water is matched i need the word water.

example table

```
--------------------------------------------------------
    id|                 text1 |               text2
--------------------------------------------------------
1       rain water harvesting    I have a new car
2       summer season heat       I want to make tea
3       I want to go to paris    I love to water plants
4       Its raining in england   rain drops are falling
5       do not waste water       we eat bun
6       water is essential       I love to dance in rain
7       fire burns               my laptop is old
8       we breathe air           We eat good food
---------------------------------------------------------
```

This is the query I have reached so far

```
SELECT *,
       MATCH(text1,text2) AGAINST('rain water' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE) AS Word 
  FROM EXAMPLE_TABLE 
 WHERE MATCH(text1,text2) AGAINST('rain water' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE)
```

Comment: Please dont downvote ... I didnt find any answers and trying to learn here.

Comment: then add example data and wanted result.

Comment: You cannot do this in mysql with fulltext searc. Either you need to do simple pattern matching or ou need to search for the two words separately.

Comment: Show us the result you want to get, maybe there is another approach.

Comment: Specifically, you should define how the the result should look like if both words are found (like in your first text) (e.g. you want to get two rows, a comma or space separated list, an error, just the first matching word, ...).

Comment: @Solarflare .... lets say , I need the result to be matched word like in line number 6, i need water, rain

Answer (score 0):

MySQL does not directly offer you feedback about why your search term hit, apart from the aggregated score.

You can however extract that information if you match your result to each term separately, and this way create your own post-evaluation:

```
SELECT *, 
    CONCAT_WS(', ', 
              IF(MATCH(text1,text2) AGAINST('rain'), 'rain', null),
              IF(MATCH(text1,text2) AGAINST('water'), 'water', null) ) as words
FROM EXAMPLE_TABLE 
WHERE MATCH(text1,text2) AGAINST('rain water')
```

This will check your found rows against each term separately, and if it was a hit,  appends the word to your result string.

In general though, things you do just to format your output belong into your application, which also usually has more flexibility in processing strings. If you e.g. want to order your terms by position or occurance in your result ("water, rain" instead of "rain, water"), a query-only solution will quickly become a mess (and if you'd still need it in MySQL, you would do it in a stored function and do basically the same as you would in e.g. php).